# Make Hello + first name + last name in the same line

Tags: flutter

I don't know what is wrong here, it's pretty easy to solve, but you already know stupid things happened while coding.

I'm trying to make the Hello First name Last name in the same line, but can't think anymore, what shall I do please?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NefertitiSheetView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            S.of(context).welcome_hello,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
          ),
          BlocBuilder<RiderProfileCubit, GetCurrentOrder$Query$Rider?>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Text(
                "${state?.firstName != null ? " ${state!.firstName!} ${state!.lastName!}" : ""}!",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
              );
            },
          ).pOnly(bottom: 2),
```

Photo:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap both elements inside a Row. They are just in a Column right now.

```
Row(
children: [
Text(
            S.of(context).welcome_hello,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
          ),
          BlocBuilder<RiderProfileCubit, GetCurrentOrder$Query$Rider?>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Text(
                "${state?.firstName != null ? " ${state!.firstName!} ${state!.lastName!}" : ""}!",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
              );
            },
          ).pOnly(bottom: 2),
],
),
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly .. and thanks for mention the Wrap as well, I forgot it.